# Android Controlling a button inside a custom list view

Tags: android, listview

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Holder holder=new Holder();
    View rowView;
    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.receiptlistsample, null);
    holder.product=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.product);
    holder.quantity=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.quan);
    holder.price=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.price);
    holder.add = (ImageButton)rowView.findViewById(R.id.plus);
    holder.cancel = (ImageButton)rowView.findViewById(R.id.minus);
    holder.product.setText(pro[position]);
    holder.quantity.setText(quant[position]);
    holder.price.setText(pri[position]);
    holder.add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
               Toast.makeText(context, "add ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    holder.cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "cancel ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    return rowView;
}}
```

I am having a problem using a customAdapter for listview which has a custom layout with Textview and two buttons add and cancel.
I want to call a method from the MainActivity once the button add or cancel is pressed. The toast is working fine but I can not call a method.

Comment: use listner for that and pass it to main activity to call method of main actiivity

Comment: can u elaborate a little more ?

Comment: You need to create listener `interface`  and pass it to your adapter and implement into your activity

Comment: check my answer @ahemd

Comment: you should use ((nameOfYourActivity)context).nameofyourmethod();

Comment: @jaydeeppipaliya Thanks Man, that worked for me,

Comment: @Hasmukhthe interface got some nullpointerexception on it but thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

do this way first create interface

```
public interface GetData {
    public void getvalue(String flag);
}
```

now pass it with adapter calling

```
mAdapter = new SearchAdapter(Search_Data.this, eventlistsubcat, new GetData() {
                    @Override
                    public void getvalue(String flag) {

                        strlistner=flag.toString();

                      if(strlistner.equals("add")){
                        //call your add method
                        }
                    }
                });
```

in adapter class

declare object of interface

```
 GetData listner;
```

and initialize in constructor

```
 public SearchAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<abx_Detail> feedItemList, GetData listner) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.feedItemList = feedItemList;
        this.listner=listner;
        itemcheck = new boolean[feedItemList.size()];
    }
```

the on click of your button call like this

```
listner.getvalue(flag);
```

so check or call method according flag value in mainactivity. where you call you adapter